# Ruby on Rails - span tag refresh by javascript in link_to

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have a span tag which is refreshed by javascript. So in my view, this code will display the number :

```
<span id="actual_nbr"></span>   # Show the number via javascript
```

The javascript looks like :

```
document.getElementById("actual_nbr").innerHTML = 1;
```

Now I want to use this value in a link_to to create an object :

```
<%= link_to "OK", { :action => "create", :nbr => content_tag(:span, 'actual_nbr') }, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :create %>
```

If I inspect my element I get :

```
<a confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="create" href="/purchases?nbr=%3Cspan%3Eactual_nbr%3C%2Fspan%3E" rel="nofollow">OK</a>
```

And, it returns me an error because span tag is considered as text not html tag :

```
{"_method"=>"create",
 "authenticity_token"=>"7CC6I1HrmFZcT2Qrkriafago1ZGhizX4cJL+FaSyRkw=",
 "nbr"=>"<span>actual_nbr</span>"}
```

What is the best way to do what I'm trying to do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Ajax to resolve my problem.

In my javascript :

```
function submitForm() {
      $.ajax({
           type:'POST', 
           url: '/purchases', 
           data: $.param({ purchase: {id: variable_id, nbr: variable_nbr }})
      });
 }
```

In my view :

```
<button type="button" onclick="submitForm()">Send data</button>
```

In my controller :

```
def create
        Rails.logger.debug "***************************************"
        Rails.logger.debug params
        Rails.logger.debug "***************************************"
        @purchase = current_user.purchases.create(purchase_params)
        if @purchase.save
            redirect_to @purchase.paypal_url(user_path(current_user), purchase_params[:id], purchase_params[:nbr])
        else
            redirect_to(root_url)
        end
    end
```

I also used purchases.**create** instead of purchases.*build*

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is server-side and can't view the result of what JavaScript does client-side, so you can't do this without some help from JavaScript. I would suggest adding an id to your element from Rails such as
`id: "purchaseIt"`
and add an HTML5 data attribute to your anchor:
`data-nbr="nojs"`
then update the element from JavaScript with what you need: `document.getElementById('purchaseIt').setAttribute('data-nbr','1');`